# Can't remove gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, uninstallation, breadcrumbs

Have a very strange problem. I have RVM and rails project. I used 'breadcrumbs_on_rails' gem and I had it in my Gemfile. After one update I got some errors in this gem, so I tried to roll back to previous version. I wrote version in Gemfile, ran bundle update - but nothing changed, there were still errors. I tried totally remove this gem from Gemfile, but... it's helpers were still working! I uninstalled gem completely, all versions, by running gem uninstall, cleared tmp folder of project, rebooted, but it is still working. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in conflict of two gems
gem twitter-bootstrap-rails have exactly same methods - add_breadcrumb and render_breadcrumbs. And breadcrumbs were rendered by this gem, not by breadcrumbs_on_rails.
So, it turns out, that gem was removed successfully

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
bundle exec gem uninstall GEM_NAME
```

For RVM users: 
you have to use this method if you've set up a gemset for your particular project.

Running gem uninstall GEM_NAME from the project folder will uninstall GEM_NAME from your global/system level gemset instead of bundler's.